# how to do a dot product with x1,…,xn and print then in a specific way

Tags: python

I have a basic question. I am trying to make some constraints for an optimization software. could you please help me to do this:

I have a couple of vectors of numbers for example :`(1 4 2 3 4 1) , (1 1 2 6 8 9)`

I want the first one multiply by `x1` the second by `x2` and ... . I want the out put be like this:

`s.t. a1: 1*x1+4*x2+2*x3+3*x4+4*x5+1*x6>=0;`

`s.t. a2: 1*x1+1*x2+2*x3+6*x4+8*x5+9*x6>=0;`

so I want the term `s.t. ai:` to be printed in front of `i-th` constraint and `>=0;` at the end of each constraint.

Note that I have the vectors of number but not `x1,x2,...,xn`. Since my vectors are large it is hard for me to make the list of `x1,x2,...,xn`.

here is what I did :

```
y="1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1"
xx=list(y.split(" "))
x=[]
for i in range(1,42):     #I know it is not correct to define (x1,...,x42) like this, but 
          x=xi                #what is the correct way?

def dot(x, y):
    return sum(x_i*y_i for x_i, y_i in zip(x, xx))

print("s.t. a:" dot(x, y) ">=0;")
```

my problem is I can not define x=(x1,...,x42) correctly. and in print I can't print `ai`

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you are trying to achieve here? How does x1 ... x42 show up in your desired output?

Comment: this code is not correct I want the output be same as line 5 and 6 in my question!

Comment: Your output has only x1, x2, and x3, does this mean you do not need x4, x5, ... x42?

Comment: I used x1,x2,x3 in the sample to show how the output must be! in the code its x1,...,x42. it was hard to show the output x1,...,x42

Comment: OK, can you provide an example with x4, x5, and x6 to clarify?

Comment: I added `x4,x5,x6`

Comment: Ok, now I understand, let's see what we can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
# create vectors:
vector = [1, 4, 2]

# initialize empty equation:
equation = ''

# loop over every point in the vector:
for index, point in enumerate(vector):

    # update the equation for each point in the vector:
    equation += str(point) + '*x_' + str(index+1) + ' + ' 

# remove the trailing ' + ' from equation:
equation = equation[0:-3]

# add head and tail to equation:
equation = 's.t. a1: ' + equation + ' >=0;'

# print result:
print(equation)
```

Will output this:

```
s.t. a1: 1*x_1 + 4*x_2 + 2*x_3 >=0;
```

You can change the vector as needed.

Comment: where did you define the vectors? (1,4,2) and (1,1,2)?

Comment: See the latest update - let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: Strange: I changed 3 to 42 but it print the inequality until x37! can you see why?

Comment: Can you share the new code? Where did you change the answer exactly?